# Applet that can access users' files on their machine

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet, certificate

Is it possible to create a Java applet that will be able to access users' files on their private machines?

I have a Java applet that is self signed and loads nicely, but when I try to select a file, it doesn't work and gives me the following exception:

```
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied   
(java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:667)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolderManager.get(ShellFolderManager.java:56)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(ShellFolder.java:227)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getDefaultDirectory(FileSystemView.java:391)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(JFileChooser.java:552)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:334)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:316)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at ca.file.FileUtils.getFile(FileUtils.java:175)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at ca.file.FileUtils.getStructureFile(FileUtils.java:288)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at ca.uielements.Core.getStructureFile(Core.java:421)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at ca.uielements.Core.actionPerformed(Core.java:444)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1223)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:137)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1264)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6348)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3255)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6113)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4714)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:635)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
14-01-08 10:41:15 PM    [0x0-0x148148].com.apple.Safari[2987]       atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

The issue is that I am creating a new `JFileChooser` in the line it crashes. The original point of this applet is to allow users to view certain structure files without having to download the software, just going online and having it work. However, I do not have the funds to pay for a professional certificate, nor do I know if I had one would my applet be allowed to access users' files then?

Here is a simple applet class that demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

public class simpleApplet extends JApplet {

static final String message = "Shlonsky!";
private Font font = new Font("serif", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 36);

public void init() {
    // set the default look and feel
    String laf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException exc) {
        System.err.println ("Warning: UnsupportedLookAndFeel: " + laf);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.err.println ("Error loading " + laf + ": " + exc);
    }
    getContentPane().setLayout (null);
}

public void start()
{
    JFrame vizFrame = new JFrame("myFrame");
    vizFrame.setBackground(Color.white);
    vizFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    vizFrame.setSize(800, 650);
    vizFrame.setVisible(true);


    File previousFile = null;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(previousFile);  // This is where the program would crash
    int fileReturnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(vizFrame);
    }//end start

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(message, 40, 80);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Very strange, I just signed the simple class I made and when I run it, Safari DOES ask me whether I want to trust the applet or not, but for some reason it doesn't do so for the other applet (which is signed in the same way). Can there be something in the HTML file I am using preventing Safari from asking for approval?

Comment: *"Is it possible to create a Java applet that will be able to access users' files on their private machines?"*  Yes, it certainly should be possible to access files under `user.home` from a signed applet. What is the security prompt you see when prompted to trust the code?  Can you retype the text or provide a screenshot?  What exact version of Java is running the applet? It might pay to check the bug database for similar problems (presuming it is an Oracle JRE).

Comment: I am using Safari 4.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.3 and it isn't prompting me to do anything. It displays the JFrame in which the applet is in, and the menu items, but when I select "Load Structure" it crashes with the exception I mentioned.

If I change the permissions in my java.policy file, things are working, but that's a hack and not practical since I want the applet public.

I use regular <applet></applet> embedding to run the code

Comment: I find your reply very confusing, though I can add some details.. let's break it down..  *"I am using Safari 4.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.3 and it isn't prompting me to do anything."*  Singed code should not be launched without a prompt. *"It displays the JFrame in which the applet is in"*  What the huh?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that conectrates on havinf a frame, an applet, and a button to try and access `user.home` *:and the menu items, but when I select "Load Structure" it crashes with the exception I mentioned."* OK .. continued..

Comment: .. *"If I change the permissions in my java.policy file, things are working, but that's a hack and not practical since I want the applet public"*  I fully agree.  Glad I do not have to convince you of that. *"I use regular <applet></applet> embedding to run the code"*  OK, as long as the applet is launching I can't see it causing the problem, so I won't ask to see the HTML.

Comment: Andrew, I have added a simple example that demonstrates the problem. I hope this will help explain what I mean.